# fb-like switch colorscheme in JS

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an fb-like on my website.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/wisieleconlinepl-112995595757466/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

I want to have a Javascript function to switch data-colorscheme between dark and light without reloading the whole page. But I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions?

I tried using:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fb-like");
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I am not sure why exactly, but I think it just doesn't add this fb-like into the array.
I also tried placing the fb-like in a div and switching innerHTML of that div, but id also didn't work.

Is it possible to switch the colorscheme of my FB-like with Javascript? I want to be able to change the fb-like dynamically on the page. How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function changeColorScheme() {
    var current = $('.fb-like').data('colorscheme');
    $('.fb-like').data('colorscheme', current == 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark').empty();
    $('.fb-container').each(function() {
        FB.XFBML.parse(this); //rerender all fb-like elements
    });
}
```

Note: FB.XFBML.parse() should be called on a parent element of the widget, not directly on the XFBML element itself. So wrap fb-likes in container for example.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a total beginner and I don't know how to implement your code. To give you more details: I have a <select> on my page. And in this <select> you can choose if you want to have black or white style of my page. And this <select> switches the CSS stylesheet linked to the page to another, with function executed onchange. And I want to execute the code to switch the colorscheme of my FB element in the function executed onchange when my <select> element is changed.

And wrap fb-like in a cointainer? Just put it into another div? Could you show me exactly how would that look like?

Comment: Also, is this pure Javascript?

Comment: No, it's jquery. Here is pure javascript example: http://www.ajdnes.sk/stack/colorscheme.php

Comment: Thanks for this pure javascript example. I am a beginner and I don't know much about jquery, so I prefer using pure javascript. Your pure javascript example is just great. Thanks.